# SAP B1 SQL Query and selection criteria

Tags: mysql, sapb1

I'm new to SAP B1 and SQL and trying to create a query for invoice summary in query manager. Just a few questions..

1. Can I generate a column total automatically without ctrl+clicking on the colulmn?
2. Instead of filtering by WhsCode eg ABC, BCA, in Criteria Selection when executing query, I want to be able to choose from the list of  A/R Invoice SeriesNames instead such as IN-ABC, IN-BCA in which it will then show me all Invoices where DocNum column starts with the chosen SeriesName prefix.
3. If I use whscode filter, how can I add a wildcard option such that if user does not select a warehouse, it will just display all warehouses.
4. Currently date filter lets me select a range of posting dates. Can I have the criteria selection show me a calender range instead of a list of documents?

Thank you.

```
Declare @Date1 Datetime
Declare @Date2 Datetime
Set @Date1 = (select min(S0.DocDate) from OINV S0 Where S0.DocDate >= '[%0]')
Set @Date2 = (select max(S1.DocDate) from OINV S1 Where S1.DocDate <= '[%1]')
SELECT 
DISTINCT CONCAT(T1.[SeriesName], T0.[DocNum]) AS DocNum,
T2.[WhsCode],
T0.[CardName] AS 'Customer Name', 
T0.[DocDate],
T0.[DocCur], 
T0.[PaidSum],
T0.[DocStatus]
FROM 
OINV T0  INNER JOIN NNM1 T1 ON T0.Series = T1.Series INNER JOIN INV1 T2 ON T0.[DocEntry] = T2.[DocEntry]
WHERE 
T0.[DocDate] BETWEEN @Date1 AND @Date2
AND
T0.[DocStatus] = 'C' 
AND
T2.[WhsCode] = '[%]'
```

I have tried

WHERE
T1.[SeriesName] = '[%]'

to filter by SeriesName, but it gives me the entire system list of document series names when I only want series under A/R Invoice.